# How to map int to a list in redis?

Tags: python, redis

I want to map numbers to list in redis

I currently have: r.set(r_id, [d_id,l_id,in_state], ex=10)

But it says this while running: Invalid input of type: 'list'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.

Here I want to map: r_id -> [d_id,l_id,in_state]

how do i do this?

Answer (score 3):

As you notice, `SET` doesn't accept list as value, but only simple values.

To work with lists, you should use the [list-based commands](https://redis.io/commands/?group=list).

Specifically, to map a key to a list, you can use the [RPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpush/) command (note that it appends elements if the list already exists).
You haven't mentioned what client you use. Assuming it's `redis-py`, you would do:

```
r.rpush(r_id, d_id, l_id, in_state)
```

See documentation [here](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.rpush).

You can find more information about Redis lists [here](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/lists/).

Comment: thanks, do you also know how to set expiry for the key value ?

Comment: the 'expire' command does it - https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.expire